# Selenium Java : Handling check boxes

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1LB4.jpg)
I have to test a question-answer module where user will enter answers through check box. There are total 5 j-query tabs with some questions. and it will move to other tab if answers are given and clicked "Save and next" button. I am going following way but it is not selecting every check box. because some check boxes are not displayed. Can someone suggest better way to select each and every checkbox?

```
List<WebElement> chkbx = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
int j=1;
while(j<5){
for(int i = 0;i<chkbx.size();i++){
    if(chkbx.get(i).isDisplayed()){
        chkbx.get(i).click();
    }
}
driver.findElement(By.xpath("x-path of save button")).click();
j++;
}
```

Comment: Can you add HTML and Snap, How its looking like or can provide the url of site ?

Comment: Yes. I have attached a snap. Please take a look.

Comment: is it possible to share the URL or can you add the HTML of it ?

Comment: No. It is not possible.

Comment: Ok not an issue, I guess that you are locating your element `//input[@type='checkbox']` So might be locating all the checkboxes which are available on the page. So make it more robust just start locating it from parant element of that tab

Comment: Try this code `List<WebElement> chkbx = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
      for(WebElement e:chkbx)
      {
       
       if(e.isDisplayed())
       {
        e.click();
        Thread.sleep(1500);
       }
      }` and let me know

Comment: Yes. it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code to get all your checkboxes and perform the click operation on the  displayed checkboxes :

```
List<WebElement> chkbx =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
for(WebElement e:chkbx) 
{ 
    if(e.isDisplayed()) 
    {
       e.click(); 
       Thread.sleep(1500);
    } 
}
```